# collected 0 items while running command from terminal

Tags: python, automation, pytest

I am using below code just to check my `pytest` functionality :

```py
class test_001:

    def test_addition(self):
        assert 1 + 1 == 2
```

On running the command :

> pytest -v -s testCases/testme.py

it always shows `Collected 0 items`.
Please tell me what wrong am i doing.
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [test discovery on the pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) the defaults are to look for files named  test_*.py or *_test.py.  If you have a class then the class should start Test.

So if you rename your file testCases/test_me.py and rename the class IE:

```
class Test_001:
    def test_addition(self):
        assert 1+1 == 2
```

then pytest will find it